# how to refresh Bearer Token using retrofit android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit, okhttp

while login app i could get TOKEN, refresh token, and save it but i have no idea about when session end for token how to renew. how to add intercepter in it to renew token or some other method could be use ? here is my code

1- Api end point

```
@POST("identity/Identity/GetRefreshToken")
suspend fun refreshToken(): AuthTokenEntityDT0
```

2- AuthTokenEntityDT0 response

```
data class AuthTokenEntityDT0(
@SerializedName("accessToken") val accessToken: String,
@SerializedName("refreshToken") val refreshToken: String,
@SerializedName("statusCode") val statusCode: Int,
@SerializedName("statusMessage") val statusMessage: String,
)
```

3 - make request here

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAPIService(): ApiService {
   val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
   interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
   val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val original = chain.request()
                val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .addHeader("user-agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")
                val request = requestBuilder.build()
                chain.proceed(request)
            }
            .build()


        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(NativeBaseUrl.getBaseUrl())
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(ApiService::
        class.java)
    }


    @Provides
    fun provideApiRepository(apiService: ApiService): ApiRepository {
        return ApiRepositoryImpl(apiService)
    }
```

4 -

issue: refreshToken Api Calling repeatedly how i can stop it and
moved forward although i have put Dispatcher for one request
to move forward like this

```
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
    val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
    dispatcher.maxRequests = 1

    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(ForbiddenInterceptor(this))
        .dispatcher(dispatcher)
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; 
         charset=UTF-8")
                .addHeader("user-agent",
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 
                  10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $access_token")
            val request = requestBuilder.build()
         chain.proceed(request)
        }
        .build()
```

5- here is my intercepter

```
class ForbiddenInterceptor(var hIltModules: HIltModules) : 
Interceptor {
@Throws(IOException::class)

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val original = chain.request()
    val response = chain.proceed(original)


    if (response.code == 401) {

        val responseRefreshTokens= runBlocking {
            val originalRequests = chain.request()
            val authenticationRequest = originalRequests.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("refreshtoken", "${Constants.refreshToken}").build()
            chain.proceed(authenticationRequest)

           hIltModules.provideAPIService().refreshToken()

        }

        if (responseRefreshTokens.statusCode == 200) {
            val originalRequests = chain.request()
            val newAuthenticationRequest = originalRequests.newBuilder()
                .removeHeader("refreshtoken")
                .build()

            access_token = responseRefreshTokens.accessToken
            refreshToken = responseRefreshTokens.refreshToken

            return chain.proceed(newAuthenticationRequest)

        }


    }
    return chain.proceed(original)
}
```

}

Comment: Well, good job getting the token, you are halfway there. As for when the tokens will expire, that depends on the backend service you're working with. Conceptually, the token is what tells the backend service that your calls are valid, that you have been authenticated. Once your access or refresh token expires you will get a HTTP 401 or 403 (it really depends on the backend system) any authenticated call could result in this code - to let you know you need to renew your token.

Comment: @Marton really appreciated for help i am looking for programatically implementation e.g after 15 mint token expire so i got in response code 401, how to implement intercepter to get error 401 and renew token any suggestion appreciated  thanks

Comment: You're on the right track with your code, you've already added a custom interceptor. Do you know how to get a new token? The backend service is supposed to some sort of mechanism where you will pass the accesToken in in exchange for a refreshToken.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what goes wrong (yet). Theoretically, these are the steps:

1. authenticate or authorize the user somehow
2. you'll receive both the `accessToken` and `refreshToken`, you'll use `refreshToken` for the API calls and once you notice expiration, you'll use `accessToken` to get a new one.

Once you catch the expiration in the interceptor, I would not start a new API call inside the Interceptor. You just caught a Request, let that finish first and then start a new call. This could potentially lead to a loop you experience.

Any error message you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you put your custom interceptor in its own class, like this:

```
class ForbiddenInterceptor : Interceptor {
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
        val response: Response = chain.proceed(request)
        if (response.code == 401) {
            // this code section will run for every HTTP 401 response
        }
        return response
    }
}
```

Then use this interceptor:

```
val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(ForbiddenInterceptor())
            .build()
```

Adding the interceptor to the OkHttpClient makes sure you'll intercept the calls and you can run your custom code, check if it's been rejected by the server.

As for renewing your token. You'll probably need to implement another service of the backend. I can only assume, but you'll have to use your `accesToken` feed it into an endpoint, the server will return a fresh `refreshToken`.

Answer (score 0):

here is my full code that i have done for refresh token it may be helpful for some one

```
class AuthenticationInterceptorRefreshToken @Inject constructor(
var hIltModules: HIltModules,

) : Interceptor {
@Throws(IOException::class)
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    val originalRequest = chain.request()
    val response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)

    if (response.code == 401) {

        synchronized(this) {

            val originalRequest = chain.request()
            val authenticationRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("refreshtoken", " $refreshToken")
                .build()
            val initialResponse = chain.proceed(authenticationRequest)

            when (initialResponse.code) {

                401 -> {
                    val responseNewTokenLoginModel = runBlocking {
                        hIltModules.provideAPIService().refreshToken()
                    }

                    when (responseNewTokenLoginModel.statusCode) {
                        200 -> {
                            refreshToken = responseNewTokenLoginModel.refreshToken
                            access_token = responseNewTokenLoginModel.accessToken

                            val newAuthenticationRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                                .header("refreshtoken",
                                    " $refreshToken")
                                .build()
                            return chain.proceed(newAuthenticationRequest)
                        }
                        else -> {
                            return null!!
                        }
                    }
                }
                else -> return initialResponse
            }
        }
    }; return response
}
```

Comment: Special thanks to @Marton to give me basic idea to achieve this all